# what do you call someone who refuses to provide training when they should?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Example:**

The employee went to their manager for help on how to perform a task that was new to them. However, the manager told them that they should know how to perform this task and refused to train them.

**The manager is ...**

*Note: In this context, the manager should have no expectation that the newly hired employee should know how to perform this task.*

*Bonus:*
*The employee is ...*

Comment: A poor manager.

Comment: The manager is *hiding the fact he doesn't know how to do it either*.

Answer (score 1):

The employee is [untrained](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/untrained)

> has not been taught the skills that they need for a particular job, activity, or situation

I don't think there's a specific word for the way the manager is acting, but it would come under the heading of [unsupportive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unsupportive)

> not providing support

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe English has a single precise word to describe such a situation. Instead you might say the manager is being

- ignorant (broadly an insult to behaviour seen as stupid)
- pig-headed (broadly an insult for stubborn in a negative way)
- patronizing
- depreciative (by implictly saying the employee is lacking in a basic skill and therefore deficient)
- unhelpful
- contemptuous (by treating the employee with little respect)
- and negligent (since presumably it is the manager's job to train).

A range of words also describe the employee, including:

- ignorant (with a different connotation to the manager)
- unskilled / incompetent (unfortuately that word is now too commonly meant as insult when it is a statement of fact, either the employee is competent to perform the task or he is incompetent)
- is 'in a bit of a pickle' (colloquialism for any difficult situation)
- aggrieved (because they have suffered a grievance and have a cause for complaint by the assumption and the unhelpfulness).